# Is there a historical reason why Python split() and join() methods use opposite syntaxes?

Tags: python

It's never been clear to me why `join` and `split` have the opposite syntax from each other in Python. As in the below example:

```
some_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
some_str = ' '.join(some_list)

some_str = 'a.b.c.'
some_list = some_str.split('.')
```

Why isn't it `some_list.join(' ')`, or conversely, `'.'.split(some_str)`? Is there a historical reason for these two syntaxes being different, or is it because of something you can do with one syntax that you can't with the other?

Comment: The `''.join` syntax is great because you can use it on all kinds of iterators and even generator comprehensions, not just lists which would be inefficient

Comment: @mkrieger1 - Granted, but the order of operands is (to me) flipped. For `join`, why do you call a method on the joining character, not on the list?

Comment: Because *you can use it on all kinds of iterators and even generator comprehensions.*

Comment: Okay, the dupe does answer my question, so that's fine, thanks. I'm curious why comments keep disappearing - do authors commonly delete their own comments or do mods periodically clean up certain comments?

Comment: @deceze - That point didn't answer my question about the order of operands though

Comment: Well, it's not *operands*, it's that `join` is a method of `str`, so that it can accept *all kinds of iterators and even generator comprehensions*. The other way around `join` would need to be a method of *all kinds of iterators and even generator comprehensions* instead.

Comment: Ahh, now I'm with you. Thanks for explaining :)